# Orange performance on Association rule mining

Tags: associations, orange

I am using `orangecontrib.associate.fpgrowth` for association rules mining. Based on couple of experiment it seems as number of products increase  to above 1000 then running time increase exponentially. However, I am not sure if it is true. Is there any approximation about the complexity of algorithm and/or parameters which have most significant effect on performance (Like number of product? number of total transaction? or something else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Association rules generation algorithms in general "explode" quite fast. Rules-from-itemsets operation, in particular, I think is akin to enumerating a powerset (2<sup>n</sup>). Couldn't further elaborate on the theoretical complexity myself, but I think the runtimes for given support / confidence / avg. transaction size thresholds are comparable to those found elsewhere:

```
import time

import numpy as np
from orangecontrib.associate.fpgrowth import frequent_itemsets,\
                                             association_rules

for n_trans in (100, 1000, 10000):
    for n_items in (10, 100, 1000):
        X = np.random.random((n_trans, n_items)) > .8

        t_start = time.clock()
        itemsets = dict(frequent_itemsets(X, .05))
        n_itemsets = len(itemsets)
        t_itemsets = time.clock() - t_start

        t_start = time.clock()
        rules = list(association_rules(itemsets, .01))
        n_rules = len(rules)
        t_rules = time.clock() - t_start

        print('{:5d} {:4d}   {:5.1f} ({:7d})   {:4.1f} ({:7d})'.format(
            n_trans, n_items, t_itemsets, n_itemsets, t_rules, n_rules))
```

Outputs:

```
  100   10     0.0 (     24)    0.0 (     28)
  100  100     0.1 (   1800)    0.0 (   3880)
  100 1000    43.3 ( 470675)   15.3 (2426774)
 1000   10     0.1 (     11)    0.6 (      2)
 1000  100     0.2 (    452)    0.0 (    704)
 1000 1000    33.5 (  35448)    0.8 (  68896)
10000   10     0.1 (     10)    0.0 (      0)
10000  100     2.6 (    100)    0.0 (      0)
10000 1000   180.8 (   1000)    0.0 (      0)
```